# Перебрать ссылки в блоке

Tags: python, selenium

Помогите спарсить ссылки в цикле, не пойму как это реализовать делаю так :

```
users_url = []

for element in driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'tasks')[:20]:
    users_url.append(driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'row.taskblok').get_attribute('data-link'))
print(users_url)
```

Выдает только первый data-link и это логично. Если бы row taskblok были внутри других дивов, то можно было бы зацепиться и перебрать их внутри цикла, а так не пойму как мне это сделать.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, что проблема связана с тем, как вы пытаетесь получить доступ к атрибуту `data-link` элемента `row.taskbook`. В вашем коде вы используете метод `find_element` для поиска элемента `row.taskbook` внутри переменной `element`, которая представляет каждый элемент с именем класса `tasks`.

Вместо этого вы должны использовать метод `find_element` для поиска элемента `row.taskbook` внутри переменной `element`, которая представляет каждый элемент `task`. Вы можете сделать это, связав методы `find_element` в цепочку, например:

```py
users_url = []

for element in driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'tasks')[:20]:
    users_url.append(element.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'row.taskblok').get_attribute('data-link'))
print(users_url)
```

Этот код будет выполнять итерацию по первым 20 элементам `task` с именем класса `tasks`, и для каждого элемента он найдет внутри него элемент `row.taskblok`, а затем извлекет атрибут `data-link` этого элемента.

Я надеюсь, что это поможет!

**UPD1:**
Если код выводит только одну ссылку, возможно, что метод `find_element` неправильно находит элемент блока `row.task`. Вот несколько способов, которые вы можете попробовать для устранения проблемы:

1. Проверьте, действительно ли элементы `tasks` содержат элементы блока `row.task`. Вы можете сделать это, вручную проверив HTML-код или добавив инструкцию `print` внутри цикла, чтобы увидеть содержимое каждого элемента.
2. Попробуйте использовать метод `find_elements` вместо `find_element`. Метод `find_elements` возвращает список всех совпадающих элементов, поэтому вы можете выполнить цикл по списку и извлечь атрибут `data-link` для каждого элемента `row.taskblok`. Вот пример фрагмента кода:

```python
users_url = []

for element in driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'tasks')[:20]:
    rows = element.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'row.taskblok')
    for row in rows:
        users_url.append(row.get_attribute('data-link'))
        
print(users_url)
```

Этот код найдет все элементы блока `row.task` внутри первых 20 элементов `tasks` и добавит их атрибут `data-link` в список `users_url`.

3. Убедитесь, что страница завершила загрузку, прежде чем запускать код. Вы можете добавить инструкцию `wait` перед циклом, чтобы убедиться, что элементы `tasks` загрузились. Например:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Wait for the page to load
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
tasks = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'tasks')))

# Extract links
users_url = []
for element in tasks[:20]:
    users_url.append(element.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'row.taskblok').get_attribute('data-link'))

print(users_url)
```

Этот код будет ждать до 10 секунд, пока элементы задач появятся на странице, прежде чем извлекать ссылки. Если элементы `tasks` не будут присутствовать через 10 секунд, код вызовет исключение `TimeoutException`.

Comment: Так же выводит одну ссылку, но все же спасибо !

Comment: @teamarden обновил ответ. Можете попробовать новые предложенные мной способы после надписи UPD1